# How to check user's permissions on page?

Tags: python, django

I need to allow the user to see some parts of a page according to his permissions.

I've seen some answers here like using `@user_passes_test` ( [Django - user permissions to certain views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597401/django-user-permissions-to-certain-views) ) and checks on the template ( [Should I use Django permissions checks in the template AND the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904338/should-i-use-django-permissions-checks-in-the-template-and-the-view) ).

In the latter **@e-satis**' answer states that for my case I should use checks at the template.

My question is: How can I do this and what is the best way (performance and security wise) to do so?

To exemplify my need I thought about Facebook. In Facebook you allow certain users to see some parts of your profile page or all of it. That's exactly the behavior I need to implement.

I appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id9)

basically

```
{% if perms.foo %}
    <p>You have permission to do something in the foo app.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have permission to do anything in the foo app.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I checked that link. But I'm not actually checking permissions set for that specific app. As in my Facebook example I need to check for custom permissions, saved on my database. Is that possible with this approach? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean - the permission lookup should work for any app, not just "that specific app". And yes with this approach you can totally show/hide parts of the page depending on the user's permissions - the django documentation I linked to shows that very clearly.

Comment: Ok, and how would I add permissions using that approach? When I saw the link I thought it was only for the app scope (system permissions). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, I'm assuming you mean permissions in the context of the Django package and not authentication-checking (is_authenticated()).  This is actually pretty straight-forward and given fully in an answer **e-satis**' gives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469590/check-permission-inside-a-template-in-django).

**edit** Looks like a better answer was given.

Comment: Yes, it's not to check if the user is authenticated, but to validated if he has the permission to see that specific block/data/info. Thanks.